# Simplifying recursive mean calculation

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

If we have

E<sub>i</sub> = mean [abs (H<sub>i</sub> - p) for p in P<sub>i</sub>]

H =  mean [H<sub>0</sub>, H<sub>1</sub>, ... H<sub>i</sub>, ... H<sub>n</sub>]

P = concat [P<sub>0</sub>, P<sub>1</sub>, ... P<sub>i</sub>, ... P<sub>n</sub>]

then does there exist a more efficient way to compute

E = mean [abs (H - p) for p in P]

in terms of H, P, and the E<sub>i</sub>s and H<sub>i</sub>s, given that H, E, and P go on to be used as H<sub>i</sub>, E<sub>i</sub>, and P<sub>i</sub> for some i, at a higher recursive level?

If we store the length of P<sub>i</sub> as L<sub>i</sub> at each stage, then we can let

L = sum [L<sub>0</sub>, L<sub>1</sub>, ... L<sub>i</sub>, ... L<sub>n</sub>]

allowing us to perform the somewhat easier calculation

E = sum ([abs (H - p) for p in P] / L)

but the use of the abs function seems to severely restrict the kinds of algebraic manipulations we can use to simplify the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Imagine you have just two groups, and one group has H1 = 1 and the other group has H2 = 2.  Imagine that every p in P1 is either 0 or 2, and every p in P2 in is either 1 or 3.  Now you will always have E1 = 1 and E2 = 1, regardless of the actual values in P1 and P2.  However, you can see that if all p in P1 are 2, and all p in P2 are 1, then E will be minimized (specifically 0.5) because H = 1.5.  Or all p in P1 could be 0 and all p in P2 could be 3, in which case E would be maximized.  (specifically 1.5).  And you could get any answer for E in between 0.5 and 1.5 depending on the distribution of the p.  If you don't actually go and look at all the individual p, there's no way to tell what exact value of E you will get between 0.5 and 1.5.  So you can't do any better than O(n) time to compute E, where n is the total size of P, which is the same running time if you just compute your desired quantity E directly from it's definition formula.